# ideviceinstaller and "could not connect to lockdownd. exiting"

Tags: ios, linux, libimobiledevice

I tried to install the ipa file to my iOS devices with `ideviceinstaller`, but I got an error - "could not connect to lockdownd. exiting" with some devices not all devices.

I found the lockdown folder stored at `/var/lib/lockdown/` and I run the command `chmod 777 -R /var/lib/lockdown/`. I am sure the devices opened the developer option and `UIAutomation`.

I restarted the `usbmuxd` and still not working:

```
usbmuxd --force-exit
sudo usbmuxd -f -v
```

What is the problem, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This has helped my colleague.

Disconnect all iOS devices, then:

```
brew uninstall ideviceinstaller
brew uninstall libimobiledevice
brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
brew link --overwrite libimobiledevice
brew install --HEAD  ideviceinstaller
brew link --overwrite ideviceinstaller
sudo rm -rf /var/db/lockdown/*
```

Connect an iOS device, and choose "Trust" when prompted, after that:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/db/lockdown/
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, we resolved the problem with checking the MD5 of all dependencies. we found customer changed some files and we recovered them, now the functionality is good.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on Debian 9 connecting to iOS 11 and the solution was:

```
apt install  --target-release stretch-backports  libimobiledevice6
```

Apparently version `1.2.1` rather than `1.2.0` of `libimobiledevice` is required to connect to versions of iOS > 10.